# User name are duplicated for each login in html?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been using firebase cloud firestore. My issue is when user logged in, the user name displays on header with drop down option account, payment and logout. When user logged out and login again with same or another account details user name keeps on adding on header with previous logged in user name.

**Note: here i am using firebase authentication and cloud firestore database.**

here is my screen shot:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //initialize the firebase app
  var config = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyBDwqFKPt4D0eIspjsziweLI0nc49BRDrU",
    authDomain: "cloudthrifty-demo.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://cloudthrifty-demo.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "cloudthrifty-demo",
    storageBucket: "cloudthrifty-demo.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "638814042535"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //create firebase references
  var Auth = firebase.auth(); 
  var dbRef = firebase.database();
  var contactsRef = dbRef.ref('contacts')
  var usersRef = dbRef.ref('users')
  var auth = null;
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  //Register
  $('#registerForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#registerModal').modal('hide');
    $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>', ['center', 'info']));
    $('#messageModal').modal('show');
    var data = {
      email: $('#registerEmail').val(), //get the email from Form
      firstName: $('#registerFirstName').val(), // get firstName
      lastName: $('#registerLastName').val(), // get lastName
    };
    var passwords = {
      password : $('#registerPassword').val(), //get the pass from Form
      cPassword : $('#registerConfirmPassword').val(), //get the confirmPass from Form
    }
    if( data.email != '' && passwords.password != ''  && passwords.cPassword != '' ){
      if( passwords.password == passwords.cPassword ){
        //create the user
          firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, passwords.password).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

          })
          .then(function(user){
            //now user is needed to be logged in to save data
            auth = user;
            //now saving the profile data
          
          var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
          console.log(uid);
          db.collection("users").doc(uid).set({
            name: data.firstName
            
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
            $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        });


            $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText('Success!', ['center', 'success']))
            
            $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
            $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

          })
          .catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error creating user:", error);
            $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText('ERROR: '+error.code, ['danger']))
            
          });
      } else {
        //password and confirm password didn't match
        $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText("ERROR: Passwords didn't match", ['danger']))
      }
    }  
  });

  //Login
  $('#loginForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
    $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>', ['center', 'info']));
    $('#messageModal').modal('show');

    if( $('#loginEmail').val() != '' && $('#loginPassword').val() != '' ){
      //login the user
      var data = {
        email: $('#loginEmail').val(),
        password: $('#loginPassword').val()
      };
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
        .then(function(authData) {
          auth = authData;
          $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText('Success!', ['center', 'success']))
          $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
          $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
          $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Login Failed!", error);
          $('#messageModalLabel').html(spanText('ERROR: '+error.code, ['danger']))
          $('#messageModal').modal('hide');
          $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
        });
    }
  });

  $('#logout').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
      // window.location='index.html';
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
  });

  //save contact
  $('#contactForm').on('submit', function( event ) {  
    event.preventDefault();
    if( auth != null ){
      if( $('#name').val() != '' || $('#email').val() != '' ){
        contactsRef.child(auth.uid)
          .push({
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            location: {
              city: $('#city').val(),
              state: $('#state').val(),
              zip: $('#zip').val()
            }
          })
          document.contactForm.reset();
      } else {
        alert('Please fill at-lease name or email!');
      }
    } else {
      //inform user to login
    }
  });

  // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  //   if (user) {
  //     auth = user;
  //     $('body').removeClass('auth-false').addClass('auth-true');
  //     usersRef.child(user.uid).once('value').then(function (data) {
  //       var info = data.val();
  //       console.log(info);
  //       // if(user.photoUrl) {
  //       //   $('.user-info img').show();
  //       //   $('.user-info img').attr('src', user.photoUrl);
  //       //   $('.user-info .user-name').hide();
  //       // } else if(user.displayName) {
  //       //   $('.user-info img').hide();
  //       //   $('.user-info').append('<span class="user-name">'+user.displayName+'</span>');
  //       // } else if(info.firstName) {
  //       //   $('.user-info img').hide();
  //       //   $('.user-info').append('<span class="user-name">'+info.firstName+'</span>');
  //       // }
  //     });
  //     contactsRef.child(user.uid).on('child_added', onChildAdd);
  //   } else {
  //     // No user is signed in.
  //     $('body').removeClass('auth-true').addClass('auth-false');
  //     auth && contactsRef.child(auth.uid).off('child_added', onChildAdd);
  //     $('#contacts').html('');
  //     auth = null;
  //   }
  // });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      auth = user;
      var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      console.log(uid);
      $('body').removeClass('auth-false').addClass('auth-true');
      db.collection("users").doc(uid)
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());

        var name = doc.data().name
        $('.user-info').append('<span class="user-name">'+name+'<span class="caret"></span></span>');
        console.log(name);
    });
    } else {
      // User is signed out.

      $('body').removeClass('auth-true').addClass('auth-false');
      auth && contactsRef.child(auth.uid).off('child_added', onChildAdd);
      
      $('#contacts').html('');
      auth = null;
    }
  });
});

function onChildAdd (snap) {
  $('#contacts').append(contactHtmlFromObject(snap.key, snap.val()));
}
 
//prepare contact object's HTML
function contactHtmlFromObject(key, contact){
  return '<div class="card contact" style="width: 18rem;" id="'+key+'">'
    + '<div class="card-body">'
      + '<h5 class="card-title">'+contact.name+'</h5>'
      + '<h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">'+contact.email+'</h6>'
      + '<p class="card-text" title="' + contact.location.zip+'">'
        + contact.location.city + ', '
        + contact.location.state
      + '</p>'
      // + '<a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>'
      // + '<a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>'
    + '</div>'
  + '</div>';
}

function spanText(textStr, textClasses) {
  var classNames = textClasses.map(c => 'text-'+c).join(' ');
  return '<span class="'+classNames+'">'+ textStr + '</span>';
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4F5459;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #71D72C;
}



/* @media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) {



}


@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {

} */


.userAuth {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0 0;
}
.modal-header:last-child{
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  max-width: calc(25% - 2em);
}

.user-info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
.user-info img{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 2em;
}

.auth-true .authenticated,
.auth-false .unauthenticated {
  display: block;
}
.auth-true .unauthenticated,
.auth-false .authenticated {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
   
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/captcha.css">
  
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body onLoad="ChangeCaptcha()" class="auth-false">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #6c757d; min-height: 50px"> 
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: aliceblue; font-size: 25px" href="#">demo</a>
            </div>
        
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                <!-- <li class="active" ><a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">What We Do <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li> -->
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">menu1</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">menu2 </a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">menu3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">menu4</a></li>
               
                <!-- <li><button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn  userAuth unauthenticated" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: 0; box-shadow: none!important;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</button></li> -->
                <li><button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn  userAuth unauthenticated" style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: 0; box-shadow: none!important;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</button></li>
               <!-- <li><a href="#" class=" userAuth authenticated user-info" style="color: #71D72C; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600" alt="User"></a></li> -->
               <!-- <li><span class="userAuth authenticated user-info"><img src="./user.svg" alt="User" class="rounded-circle"></span></li> -->

               <!-- <div class="userAuth authenticated pull-right">
                  <span class="user-info">
                    <img src="./user.svg" alt="User" class="rounded-circle">
                  </span>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="logout">Logout</button>
                </div> -->
                <!-- <li><button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn userAuth authenticated" id="logout"   style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: 0; box-shadow: none!important;">Logout</button></li> -->

                <button class="btn  navbar-btn userAuth unauthenticated" style="background-color: #71D72C; color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px;">Free Trail</button>


                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" id="options" class="navbar-btn dropdown-toggle userAuth authenticated user-info" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #fff; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; background-color: #ffffff00;" alt="User"></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        
                      <li><a href="#" role="button" class="btn  userAuth authenticated" id="Account"  style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; text-align: left;" >Account</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" role="button" class="btn  userAuth authenticated" id="Scheduler"  style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; text-align: left;" >payment</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#" role="button" class="btn  userAuth authenticated" id="logout"  style="color: #4F5459; font-size: 18px; text-align: left;" >Logout</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <main class="authenticated">
          <center>
              <h1>welcome to cloud thrifty</h1>
          </center>
          <div id="contacts"></div>
        </main>
        <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Register" aria-hidden="true" >
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <form id="registerForm" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="registerModalLabel">Register</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerFirstName"required>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerLastName"required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerEmail"required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerPassword"required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerConfirmPassword"required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn pull-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #71D72C; border: 0px; color:#fff;">Login</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="doRegister" style="background-color: #71D72C; border: 0px">Register</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true" >
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <form id="loginForm" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Login</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginEmail"required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword"required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn pull-right" style="background-color: #ffffff00; color: #4F5459; font-size: 14px; text-align: left">Forgot password?</button><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal" data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #71D72C; border: 0px;color:#fff;">Register Now</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="doLogin" style="background-color: #71D72C; border: 0px" >Login</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
    <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

    <!-- Comment out (or don't include) services that you don't want to use -->
    <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-storage.js"></script> -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <!-- <script  src="js/index.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script  src="js/login.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script  src="js/captcha.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the user's authentication state changes (i.e. they log in or out), you do:

```
$('.user-info').append('<span class="user-name">'+name+'<span class="caret"></span></span>');
```

So you're appending their new state to the existing contents of the `.user-info` element.

To replace the existing value, use `.html` instead of `.append`:

```
$('.user-info').html('<span class="user-name">'+name+'<span class="caret"></span></span>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. It works fine now but when i logout and clicked login button to login again, login button does not work. After click multiple times it works...